# Revert "sudo killall xorg"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, screen

I had a software rendering activated and tried updating my nvidia driver which didn't work as the xorg server was running. I then looked it up and found the command "sudo killall xorg" which promptly shutdown my device. on reboot my second screen does not display anything but the cursor. Also I can click on the stuff that should eb there and it works but nothing can be seen.
How can I revert this command?

Comment: You can't, that just killed the running X process, it should't have made any changes that persist after reboot. Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What hardware are you using? Which Ubuntu Version? Which Ubuntu flavor? What is your graphics card and driver (see `inxi -G`)? Anything in the logs? Try `journalctl -xb   | grep -i Xorg`.

Comment: well in the problem was that by running this command I somehow deactivated the nvidia driver and linux reset to the nouveau driver and I had to just install the newest nvidia driver via apt-get, then reboot, then choose the new driver in Software and updates.